# Android: How to bind Notification action to activity Dynamically in Android Manifest file?

Tags: android, notifications, android-manifest, android-notifications

I have an issue while binding the Notification action to the activity to receive a  push notification. I am using the following code to receive push notification on a specific activity.

```
<activity android:name=".controllers.activities.myactivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mypackage.MYAppName.NOTIFICATION" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I am using different types of build variants, So i want to update the value com.mypackage.MYAppName.NOTIFICATION as per the build type.

I tried adding a string value as below to the test build. which is specific to test build varient.

```
<string name="notification_action">com.mypackage_test.MYAppName_test.NOTIFICATION/string>
```

I took this string value and added it to the activity as below.

```
<activity android:name=".controllers.activities.myactivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="@string/notification_action" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

When i click on the notification for the first case my activity is opened but where as in the second case its not opening the activity.

Can somebody help me finding the solution to this issue.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only work around i did was, creating two different values in String.xml which is app-name and app-label. app-label value I have assigned it to the label in manifest and used app-name for the above mentioned Notifications. Here the app-label had a value with spaces its the actual app name we see under the app icon in our phone. And the app-name is some text without spaces which could be used for our Notifications